# Proving Independence with 3 different variables, but only 2 different equations

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, independence, density-function

If there are 3 i.i.d variables (X1, X2, and X3) with the same marginal probability density functions, but only 2 equations (Y1 and Y2) that contain some combination of those 3 variables, would it be possible to prove that those equations are independent of one another by developing a joint pdf f(Y1, Y2) and then proving that f(Y1, Y2) = f(Y1)*f(Y2), or would we need to use another method? I don't know how I would be able to develop a Jacobian with these equations.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  A well known example would be where $X_1,X_2,X_3$ iid $N(0,1)$ $Y_1=\frac13(X_1+X_2+X_3)$ and $Y_2=\frac12((X_1-Y_1)^2+(X_2-Y_1)^2+(X_3-Y_1)^2)$

Comment: How would you be able to conduct the inverse transformation to create the Jacobian, though, since you have 3 variables, but only 2 equations?